# Unsure of how to test for both a trigger and helper class

Tags: helper

I have a trigger and helper class to populate an account ID on a custom object prior to the record being inserted into the custom object. Can anyone help me with a test class?

Comment: Hi jks841. Our format focuses on _specific, detailed questions_ about work you've done so far. We have great resources for learning to write test classes, which I linked on [your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316233/helper-trigger-testing-assistance). SFSE does not write test classes, however. You can learn more about our format by taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Helper & Trigger Testing Assistance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316233/helper-trigger-testing-assistance)